# Bluetooth Device Connectivity issue

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am developing an android app where in i am checking if two devices are connected via  bluetooth

I am Registering the Broadcast Reciever using the below code.

```
    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);

    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2);
```

The BroadcastReceiver looks like this.

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action))
        {   
            Log.e("bluetooth connected","bluetooth connected");
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action))
        {
            Log.e("bluetooth not connected","bluetooth not connected");
        }    
    }
};
```

How ever this is not working. Not Sure Where i am going wrong. Please Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have BLUETOOTH permission in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

also instead of registering a receiver twice and using two filters you could do

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);    

this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: I have added the permission and used the same code above. Not Working. It is not calling the BroadcastReceiver!!

Answer (score 0):

did u try bluetooth-admin permission?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: Yes. I have added this permission.

Answer (score 0):

The Android documentation states that "ACL connections are managed automatically by the Android Bluetooth stack". Probably, they are not expected to be managed at application level; `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED` and `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED` dispatching depends on device and firmware version (for instance, I experienced that the Nexus S dispatches them correctly, while the older GT-I5800 doesn't).